# Recommendation for first book to proof writing

Tags: formal-proofs

I have a friend who is a third year physics undergrad. She wants to take her first proof based math course and she's decided on Abstract Algebra where the professor follows the book written by Dummit.

What is a good book can she use for a month or less in the summer holidays where she can get a nice introduction to truth tables, a bit of set theory, the different methods of proofs, a first look at relations and functions, etc? Basically something that can capture the main points needed from an Intro to Formal Math or Discrete Math course to transition into courses like Algebra or Real Analysis.

Comment: Velleman's *How to Prove It* covers a bit of all those topics you mentioned. You can also see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62629/textbook-recommendations-for-undergraduate-proof-writing-class).

Comment: Ok I'll check out the content of this book. thank you